# Remove everything after `xml_` in all filenames in directory

Tags: linux

I want to remove the timestamp from all the files in a directory

Let's say I have below files

```
ABC.xml_202401012300
XYZ.xml_202401022300
```

I want to remove all after `xml_`

This means I'm expecting

```
ABC.xml
XYZ.xml
```

I tried bellow code but did not work :

```
rename 's/xml_.*$/.xml/' *
```

Comment: Try asking in Superuser.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use `mv` to rename a file in Linux shell. If you want to rename mutliple xml files, you can do it the following way:

`for f in *.xml_*; do mv "$f" "${f%_*}"; done`

Here `%_*` is a pattern remover which says remove everything after the underscore symbol.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to do by using bellow command

```
for file in *.xml_*; do
    mv "$file" "${file%%_*}.xml"
done
```

Comment: The chosen option wouldn't work when the file has multiple "_"s in it.
e.g., ABC_PQR.xml_202401012300

To cover such cases, the selected option will work perfectly.